# Program is not creating text files within directory path

Tags: c#

So I'm having a small issue where I'm creating a directory and within that directory I'm making text files. It seems that it is only making the text files when the directory path is set to that of something like this `@"C:\Users\user1\Desktop\folder1\file.txt"`, and otherwise it creates my folders, but not my text files.

Does anyone know why that is or how I can change my code to allow for the text files to be made anywhere else I wish?

Here is the code I'm trying to get to work:

```
            string file1 = "file1.txt";
        string file2 = "file2.txt";
        string file3 = "file3.txt";
        string file4 = "file4.txt";

        string Path1 = @".\Saved_Game\Profile 1";

        if (!Directory.Exists(Path1))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path1);

        D1 = @".\Saved_Game\Profile 1\file1.txt";
        D2 = @".\Saved_Game\Profile 1\file2.txt";
        D3 = @".\Saved_Game\Profile 1\file3.txt";
        D4 = @".\Saved_Game\Profile 1\file4.txt";

        if (!Directory.Exists(D1))
            Path.Combine(Path1, file1);
        if (!Directory.Exists(D2))
            Path.Combine(Path1, file2);
        if (!Directory.Exists(D3))
            Path.Combine(Path1, file3);
        if (!Directory.Exists(D4))
            Path.Combine(Path1, file4);
```

This exact code, with the altered directory path directed to my desktop of course, is used and works, so I'm unsure of why one path works and the other does not.

Comment: This code doesn't create any files. It only creates directory `Path1`. Please, post complete code sample.

Comment: Please try to avoid relative paths - at least use [GetFullPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) to see what complete path your are using.

Comment: `Directory.Exists(D1)` why are you checking for a directory if `D1` refers to a file? `Path.Combine(Path1, file4)` is pointless if the result is not assigned.

Comment: `Path.Combine(string, string);` returns a combined path, but you're not assigning it to anything.  Is there code after this that wants to use the combined path value?

Comment: D1 ALREADY has file name in it D1 = @".\Saved_Game\Profile 1\file1.txt";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but if your motive is to create file then do like this:

```
              if (!File.Exists(D1))
                  File.Create(D1);
              if (!File.Exists(D2))
                  File.Create(D2);
              if (!File.Exists(D3))
                  File.Create(D3);
              if (!File.Exists(D4))
                  File.Create(D4);
```

It create file only if file not exists.